# SQL: perform same operation on all rows

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, row

I'm using MySQL and I have a column of dates that were enterered into the database incorrectly. More specifically, they were entered in as dd/mm/yy but MySQL assumed they were in the format yyyy/mm/dd. I made the following code to correct this problem but there is an error stating that the subquery in the first line returns more than one row. How can I make it perform this operation on every row? Do I need a loop?

```
SET @raw_date = (SELECT j.a_date FROM tbl_job j);

SET @first = SPLIT_STR(@raw_date, '-', 1);
SET @second = SPLIT_STR(@raw_date, '-', 2);
SET @third = SPLIT_STR(@raw_date, '-', 3);

SET @first = (SELECT RIGHT(@first, 2));

SET @job_date = CONCAT(@third,'-',@second,'-',@first);

UPDATE tbl_job
SET tbl_job.a_date = @job_date;
```

Comment: What type is your column?

Comment: It is a date type. The values were initially entered as strings and MySQL interpreted them backwards as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: If I`m not mistaken date field only stores dates as y-m-d,however you can retrieve the dates any way you want.SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_field, '%d/%m/%Y') http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT j.a_date FROM tbl_job 
UPDATE tbl_job
SET tbl_job.a_date = @job_date
```

eliminate `WHERE` clause, it will update all rows...

Comment: Thanks this is close to the answer I'm looking for. Unfortunately, I made my question unclear. I edited it to make it more clear.